# Fundamental group is a homotopy invariant

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am a newbie to topology and am not able to understand how to attack this problem:
Any hints would be appreciated

Assuming that:
$$
f \sim g \Rightarrow \pi_1(f) = \pi_1(g).
$$ 
Prove that the fundamental group is a homotopy invariant.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! In the future, you should say what you have tried or include your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Pick a homotopy equivalence $f: X \to Y$, with homotopy inverse $g: Y \to X$. Then by definition, $fg \sim \text{Id}_Y$ and $gf \sim \text{Id}_X$. So $\pi(fg)=\pi(f) \circ \pi(g)=\text{Id}_{\pi_1(Y)}$ and $\pi(gf)=\pi(g) \circ \pi(f)=\text{Id}_{\pi_1(X)}$, so $\pi(f)$ and $\pi(g)$ are both isomorphisms as desired.

Comment: I thought, f,g : X -> Y s.t f ~ g. In your case you assumed g is the inverse of f.

Comment: But that was not the question, seems to me

Comment: @PeterFranek I don't see how else one would interpret "is a homotopy invariant" other than "is invariant under homotopy equivalence". The OP says he's assuming $f\sim g\implies \pi_1(f)\sim \pi_1(g)$, not trying to prove it.

Comment: @Vlad I just named a different function $g$ than you did. A homotopy equivalence is a map that has a homotopy inverse (an $h:Y\to X$ such that $fh$ and $hf$ are both homotopic to the identity in their respective spaces. Now we use your assumption - that homotopic maps induce the same map on the fundamental group - to show that $\pi_1(f)$ is an isomorphism, so that if $X \simeq Y$, then $\pi_1(X)\cong\pi_1(Y)$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Right, sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Thanks for the clarification. I understand the proof. However, there is still one source of confusion: How did you infer that the question was talking about homotopic equivalence of spaces and was not talking about homotopic functions? My definition above in previous comments refers to homotopic functions, your solution refers to homotopic equivalence of spaces. Sorry, if this is obvious but I am struggling with it.

Comment: It seems I was confused and not @PeterFranek. When one says that $\pi_1$ is a homotopy invariant, it (usually - at least it does in any source I know) means that if $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent, then $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(Y)$. It didn't make sense to me that you were asking to show that if $f \sim g$ then they induce the same map on fundamental groups, since you said above that you were assuming it...

Comment: @MikeMiller: Your solution is definitely helpful in the sense of trying to get clarity of the concept. I am not looking for solutions but trying to understand the concepts. Your solution made me think more. Thank you for your response and the  discussion that followed. 
Coming back to the question: I understand the definition of homotopy invariant as you stated but can I say that if π1(f) = π1(g) then X ~ Y?

Comment: @PeterFranek: Please undelete your post, I don't remember what you posted initially.

Comment: No, @Vlad. There are lots of maps that induce the same homomorphism on fundamental groups; they don't even need to be homotopic. But if you let $f=g$ just be two maps, then $\pi_1(f) = \pi_1(g)$, but that certainly doesn't say anything about whether or not $X \simeq Y$. (I think what you want to ask is "if $\pi_1(f) = \pi_1(g)$, are $f$ and $g$ homotopic?" but the answer is no - it's the converse that's true.)

Comment: @Vlad I was just proving that $f\sim g$ implies $\pi_1(f)=\pi_1(g)$ but this was not your question, I misread it. Your question was fully answered by Mike Miller, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answwer the question (that was answered by Mike Miller) but I first thought that you ask about why $f\sim g$ implies $\pi_1(f)=\pi_1(g)$.

Let $F: X\times [0,1]\to Y$ be the homotopy between $f$ and $g$. Then for any loop $\varphi: S^1\to X$, the map $(s,t)\mapsto F(\varphi(s),t)$ is a homotopy between $f\circ\varphi$ and $g\circ\varphi$. The induced map $\pi_1(f)$ sends the class of $\varphi$ to the class of $f\circ\varphi$ and similarly for $g$, so $[f\circ\varphi]=[g\circ\varphi]$ for each $[\varphi]$ implies $\pi_1(f)=\pi_1(g)$. (All this can be formulated with base points as well.)

Comment: You need $F$ to be a pointed homotopy, fixing the base point of your fundamental group. Otherwise your $F(\varphi(\cdot),\cdot)$ will not fix the basepoint of your loops. If you only have a free homotopy, you don't get identical maps, but maps related by an isomorphism induced by the loop the basepoint travels during the homotopy.